# mysqli not work with php date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table with "data" column in varchar

[image]

and value "21/10/2017"

[image]

Now when try a query like:

```
$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($bd, date("j/m/y"));      
        $result = mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT * FROM tracking where data='".$data."'");
```

This query return 0, but if change data with random string like "dog" and replace data from mysql with dog the query work fine but i need the date not the dog.

If use `$data = "21//10//2017";` thw query work why?

Comment: Maybe store it as a date type and not varchar

Comment: It is a normal string, why if string equal "21/10/2017" not work?? and if it's not a date and is a serial? I need use a Date for serial number?

Comment: If use $data = "21//10//2017"; thw query work why?

Comment: Well there is a clue and a half...If you set it as a string it works.... .Have you echoed what $data is from your mysqli_real_escape_string function...

Comment: Better yet - just use $data = date("j/m/y"); and echo that. Do you know why you are escaping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you use `j/m/y`, according to [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) manual `y` returns year with last 2 digits, not 4 digits as you expect so use `Y` instead.

But to be honest you have to store date in the `date`, `datetime` or `timestamp` types, not in `varchar`.

Comment: @user1598430 You gave it away too easily. The Op never got to see it was the wrong format by debugging it by looking at the output.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw at least he knows where's official documentation.

Comment: +1  for datetime/timestamp types and as you also left out the much unnecessary  mysqli_real_escape_string nonsense in this case. Not sure why you would escape a php generated date.

Comment: I thought the problem was "/" and i have tried with escape =)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong [date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in `date`. You are getting the date as `j/m/y` which is in the format **d/mm/yy** e.g. `21/10/17` but your date/strings in the database are in the format **dd/mm/yyyy**.

To get the years in the full 4-digit version, you need to use `Y` instead of `y`, i.e.

```
$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($bd, date("j/m/Y"));
```

Note: You might also have the month and day formats wrong - you are using the single digit day and 2-digit month representation in PHP (e.g. 1/01/17 instead of 01/01/17) but your strings might use the full 2 digit - we can't tell in your date example... in that case you will need:

```
$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($bd, date("d/m/Y"));
```

Comment: And this is just one reason you would use dates instead of strings - you don't have to match the format to search for them. Other reasons are that you can't sort by date, search for date ranges, change the format for an international display, or basically do anything with the date other than just display it exactly as it is.

Comment: @J.DoeCd Don't forget your day and month format might be wrong too, as I mentioned in my answer. The `j/m/Y` format will work for the 21/10/2017 in your example but it won't work for dates like 01/10/2017